# ZooKeeper sequence concurrency

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am using the following code to produce a unique sequence of `id` numbers in a concurrent system:

```
    String idNodePath = "/somenode/idNode";
    Stat stat = null;
    Integer id = null;
    try{
        stat = zk.setData(idNodePath, new byte[0], -1);
        id = stat.getVersion();
    } catch ( KeeperException e){
        zk.create(idNodePath, null, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
        zk.getData(idNodePath, false, stat);
    }
```

I am concerned that this may not be correct way to achieve this using Zookeeper, although I did find someone else using a similar approach here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.zookeeper.user/3216 which give me a small amount of reassurance.

My question is: is this a safe thing to do in a concurrent system? Is there a guarantee that `id` numbers will be unique **and** sequential? (i.e. no gaps when all `id` numbers are put together from all concurrent processes/machines)

**Update:** Fix `NullPointerException` bug in code pointed out by AlexR (thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Your code definitely contains bug. Take a look on `stat` variable. It is `null` before `try` block and initialized there. But if `KeeperException` is thrown you arrive to the next line

```
int id = stat.getVersion();
```

that throws `NullPointerException` because `stat` is still null.

Now concerning the concurrency. As fat as I understand `zk` is a member of your class. In this case the code is incorrect too. Think about 2 threads. First evaluates line `stat = zk.setData()`, i.e. changes the state of `zk`. Second arrives to the same line and evaluates it too, i.e. changes the state of shared object `zk` according to its parameters. Then first thread calls `zk.getVersion()`, i.e. gets version according to the state that was set by thread 2.

I cannot give you any recommendations about changing your code because I do not know what would you like to achieve. If you can explain your task in details you will probably get better recommendation how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the null pointer bug, I will fix that. As for the `zk` object, each instance of it will only be called in one thread, so I don't think there is a problem there. My main concern is what if this code is running on two different servers, each of which is attached to two different servers in the ZK ensemble? Does ZK guarantee concurrency and sequentiality across servers in the ensemble?